# Populating dropdown list with hardcoded values in .NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
     public SelectList saleRange = new SelectList(new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem {  Selected = true ,Text = "--- Select date range ---", Value = "0" },
                new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "7 days", Value = "7" },
                new SelectListItem  { Selected = false, Text = "14 days", Value = "14" },
                new SelectListItem { Selected = false, Text = "21 days", Value = "21" },
                new SelectListItem  { Selected = false, Text = "30 days", Value = "30" },
            }, "Value", "Text");

}
```

My action:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
        { 
            var model = new MyClass();
            return View(model);
        }
```

And the view looks like this:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.saleRange, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.saleRange,new { @class= "select2" , @style = "width:95%;border-left:2px solid #eee" })
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.Html.SelectList' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? How can I populate the dropdownlist from my viewmodel with hardcoded values??

Comment: Just remove the cast to `(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)`

Comment: Then I get an error: Compiler Error Message: CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'ServiceStack.Html.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'

Comment: However, you do need a property on your model that stores the value of the selected item.  Thats what the first parameter of `DropDownListFor()` is supposed to be

Comment: @maccettura you mean like an integer value ?

Comment: As a side note, its pointless extra overhead to use `new SelectList(...` to generate an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one. And you cannot use the same property for the SelectList and the property your binding to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SelectList` is *not* the same thing as `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`, so there's no way to cast it to that. You could cast `saleRange.Items`, as that property of `SelectList` is in fact an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

However, that's completely unnecessary in the first place. As `saleRange` is a property on your model, it is strongly typed and you don't need to cast it to anything. `SelectList` is already a valid type to pass there, so just use `saleRange` directly.

Comment: Hey Chris thanks for reply, when I do that I get: Compiler Error Message: CS1503: Argument 3: cannot convert from 'ServiceStack.Html.SelectList' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.Selec‌​tListItem>'

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party library called ServiceStack?

Comment: That's because you're using a different `SelectList` type than what's accepted by `DropDownListFor`. You need `System.Web.Mvc.SelectList` rather than `ServiceStack.Html.SelectList`. That might simply be a mistake from importing the wrong namespace. If you intentionally wanted to use the `ServiceStack` version, then you'd need to utilize whatever is provided by that library to render their version of `SelectList`.

Answer (score 4):

Change your model to the following (note that the `SelectList` class **needs to be from namespace** `System.Web.Mvc`, not `ServiceStack`):

```
public class MyClass
{
    //You need somewhere to put the sales range thats selected
    public string SelectedSalesRange { get; set; }

    public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList SaleRange = new System.Web.Mvc.SelectList(new[]
        {
            //Note that I have removed the "Default" item
            //And the Selected=False (since the default value of a bool is false)

            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem { Text = "7 days", Value = "7" },
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem  {Text = "14 days", Value = "14" },
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem { Text = "21 days", Value = "21" },
            new System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem  { Text = "30 days", Value = "30" },
        }, "Value", "Text");

}
```

And change your view to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSalesRange, SaleRange, "--- Select date range ---")
```

If you want to use ServiceStack, then the entire nature of your question is invalid and you need to edit or ask a new question.  You have only asked about MVC5